# For $\mathfrak{p}$ being a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p})/2]$, can $\mathfrak{p}^2$ be generated by an irreducible element?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime, consider the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}\Big[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p}}{2}\Big]$ (that is, $\mathbb{Z}\left[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{p}}{2}\right]$ if $p\equiv 1(\text{mod }4)$, $\mathbb{Z}\left[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-p}}{2}\right]$ if $p\equiv 3(\text{mod }4)$. Can there be a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ and an irreducible element $a$ such that $\mathfrak{p}^2 = (a)$? I know that the only ramified prime is $p$ itself, which is not irreducible in $R$, so I would like to guess that the answer is no.

The square of a prime ideal can be generated by an irreducible element. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ we have $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2 = (2)$. So I was wondering what will happen in the ring stated in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that $\mathfrak{p}$ is any prime of order 2 in the class group of one of these fields. Then $\mathfrak{p}^2 = (\alpha)$ by definition. If $\alpha = xy$ is reducible, the only possible prime factorization of $(x)$ or $(y)$ is $\mathfrak{p}$, but this is absurd as $\mathfrak{p}$ is non-principal.

There are (conjecturally) infinitely many examples but annoyingly I don't know a single concrete one. You just need to find a $p$ such that the class group has even cardinality. I'm currently cheating by Googling a bit in another tab but I'll bet someone beats me to it.

(EDIT: no such $\mathfrak{p}$ exists, so in fact no such example exists; see the comments!)

Comment: The case in my question is precisely where there are no prime ideals of order 2 :) The class number of a quadratic field is odd if and only if its discriminant is $-4,8,-8$ or $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p$ for odd prime $p$.

Comment: Devastating. But then this proves your example can't happen, right If $\mathfrak{p}^2 = (\alpha)$ is principal, then $\mathfrak{p} = (\beta)$ itself is principal since the cardinality of the class group is odd.

Now $\beta^2 = \alpha*u$ for some unit, so $\alpha$ isn't irreducible.

Comment: Ah yes, the argument was so easy, silly me! Thanks a lot for working on my humble question :)

Comment: thank you, i learned something new about the parity of the class group!

Comment: Sorry, I realized that I was talking about the narrow class number. It is the same as the class number for imaginary quadratic fields. But the class number either is equal to or is the half of the narrow class number for real quadratic fields, depending on whether the fundamental unit has norm $-1$ or $1$. [Here](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1974-0364172-9) is a relative link.

Comment: @JianingSong ah that makes sense, so then you should be able to make real quadratic examples although i don't know any

Comment: No there are no examples, since the narrow class number being odd implies the class number being odd. :)